# How to create a dictionary from a list with an object as key

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

Specifically I want to use ToDictionary(). Here is some sample code:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int a { get; set; }
    public int b { get; set; }
    public int c { get; set; }
}

public class Key
{
    public int a { get; set; }
    public int b { get; set; }
}

public class KeyEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Key>
{
    public int GetHashCode(Key k)
    {
        int hash = 17;
        hash = hash * 23 + k.a.GetHashCode();
        hash = hash * 23 + k.b.GetHashCode();

        return hash;
    }

    public bool Equals(Key lhs, Key rhs)
    {
        return ((lhs.a == rhs.a) && (lhs.b == rhs.b));
    }
}

static List<Foo> Data = new List<Foo>();
static Dictionary<Key, int> Data_Map = new Dictionary<Key, int>( new KeyEqualityComparer() );

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Data.Add(new Foo() { a = 0, b = 0, c = 99 });
    Data.Add(new Foo() { a = 1, b = 0, c= 69 });

    // Key: new Key() { a = ???, b = ??? }
    // Value: c
    Data_Map = Data.ToDictionary(???)

}
```

Comment: I actually kinda surprised that you were able to get as far as you did and yet couldn't figure out how to call `ToDictionary`, given all of the information available in its documentation and just all over the web.  Did you look at example usage of `ToDictionary`?  Did you look at the MSDN docs for it?

Comment: Yes, I have looked but all examples just take a single member as the key.

Comment: What will you use for the int values in Data_Map?

Comment: You have a single member as the key, that member is just a `Key` instance.  The hard (er) part is defining it, which you've done.  Hence my confusion.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn `Foo.c`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Data.Add(new Foo() { a = 0, b = 0, c = 99 });
    Data.Add(new Foo() { a = 1, b = 0, c= 69 });

    // Key: new Key() { a = ???, b = ??? }
    // Value: c
    var Data_Map = Data.ToDictionary(
               x => new Key{ a = x.a, b = x.b},
               x => x.c, 
               new KeyEqualityComparer ());

}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548554.aspx

Comment: Just need to select `c` out as the value and you're set.

Comment: @Servy ah yes...you are right...misread the question re: the output. THX.

Comment: Also of note, you can use `Tuple` instead of `Key`.

Comment: Aron, how does a tuple do the IEqualityComparer thing?

Comment: @chhenning Actually very well.  It's `Equals` and `GetHashCode` are based on the underlying hashes/equals method of the members, not of the reference to the `Tuple`, which is what you did in a lot more code.

Answer (score -1):

```
Data_Map = Data.ToDitionary(key=>new Key{a = key.a, b= key.b}, 
                            value=> value.c, new KeyEqualityComparer());
```

Comment: That doesn't use the given equality comparer.

Comment: @Servy your comment missed something, can you guess?

Comment: You edited the post within the grace period.  The comment didn't miss anything.

Comment: @Servy no, you can see the *missed thing* right on your screen, of course it's not in my post.

Comment: Well, then I guess that's a lesson in why you don't post code that scrolls horizontally.

Comment: @Servy I don't like to call it a lesson, when posting code I always try to prevent the horizontal scrollbar from appearing as less as possible. I guess you have guessed it out?